# FlutterEngine did not exist

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

Using flutter sdk inside native android, on navigating to sdk part the flutter engine is created but if minimise the app and open other apps on top of the app and also in developer settings the background limit is "no background process", on reopening the app from app icon instead of recent apps, the app is opening to native android screen with error

```
AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.appandroid/io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The requested cached FlutterEngine did not exist in the FlutterEngineCache: 'flutter_engine'
04-26 16:11:29.999 24228 24228 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The requested cached FlutterEngine did not exist in the FlutterEngineCache: 'flutter_engine'
04-26 16:11:29.999 24228 24228 E AndroidRuntime:        at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.setupFlutterEngine(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:246)
04-26 16:11:29.999 24228 24228 E AndroidRuntime:        at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onAttach(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:181)
04-26 16:11:29.999 24228 24228 E AndroidRuntime:        at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:495)
04-26 16:11:30.000 24228 24228 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Handling uncaught exception "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.appandroid/io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The requested cached FlutterEngine did not exist in the FlutterEngineCache: 'flutter_engine'" from thread main
```

How to restore the app state where it was?

Tried initializing the flutter engine before super.oncreate()

Comment: Have you checked this solution https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51353

Comment: this solution didn't worked for me